# In visual studio with nuget packages is it possible to change the .dlls folder when publishing?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

i am programming with visual studio in c#.

I can change the folder structure when i build a debug and copy the .dlls to a Data folder inside the bin folder.

The problem is when i publish can i edit the .csproj to copy the .dlls to a Data folder inside bin? Or there is another solution?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 parts of your question:

How to configure solutions to build assemblies/EXE into folders of your choice - this is configured through properties of solution in VS (solution properties -> build -> output path). Also value of check "copy local" property on each reference.